# Prevent visual studio from copying .NET dependencies to Debug/Release folder

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to stop visual studio from copying dependencies to Release or Debug folder? I just want the EXE file to be placed there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

Each referenced item in the 'References' section under the project has a 'Copy Local' setting in its properties.  Set that to False.

Comment: Worth noting however that False is the default setting for items that VS 'expects' to be present on a target machine, so you'll need to do 'something' to ensure the dependencies are available at runtime..